# Printing with Java, how to mix "%.2f", variables, and regular strings on same print line?

Tags: java

What is a better way to get the same output as the following code, but without all the `System.out` repeats?

Whenever I try to combine it all one one line, the `printf` or `println` wants something else and I get an error with Netbeans.

```
    System.out.print("Thank you." + "\n" + "The resulting tip is ");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", tip);
    System.out.print(" and the total is ");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", total);
    System.out.println(".");
```

I'm trying to use the following on one line, how to include it on a single print attempt?

```
("Thank you." + "\n" + "The resulting tip is " + "%.2f", tip + "and the total is " %.2f", total + ".");
```

The program is a tip calculator, and I want to get the decimals rounded to two (ie xx.yy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("Thank you.%nThe resulting tip is %.2f and the total is %.2f%n.",
    tip, total);
```

This the beauty of printf or `System.format(...)` or `String.format(...)` in that it allows you to use format specifiers in the String, and then list the corresponding variables at the end. Note that new lines should be `"%n"` not `"\n"`.